# Is there a way to tell the last date time a table was modified in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to tell the last date time any table records were modified in SQL Server 2012? without having to put in a column for last update in table.

The idea is not to query say a 10 million record table when no rows were changed.

Comment: NO. If you want to know when a row was updated you have to write code for it and store that information somewhere (most logical location is a column in that row).

Comment: `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` can give a good hint in that direction but can't be relied on as only holds values for objects where the metadata is in cache, the cache doesn't survive server restarts. Also the timings are for query plans containing an update - not necessarily actual updates.

Comment: To add to what @MartinSmith already said, that DMV would show you information about the table, not information about a specific row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell the last date time any table records were
>   modified in SQL Server 2012? without having to put in a column for
>   last update in table.

Yes - you can write an update/insert/delete trigger on the table that records the fact that an update happened along with the date and time.

> The idea is not to query say a 10 million record table when no rows
>   were changed.

You might also want to look at the built in [Change Tracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964727.aspx) features